# AJAX post twice

Tags: jquery

I have an unordered list with a delete link. When the link is click an AJAX call trigger to delete the record and remove the item from the list. My AJAX call works but I notice in Firebug that it’s making the same call twice.

Anyone one knows what I’m doing wrong here? Thank you in advance for you help!

Here's my UL:

```
<UL>
    <li id="10">
        Test action <a class="deleteAction" href="10">delete</a>
    </li>
    <li id="11">
        Test action <a class="deleteAction" href="11">delete</a>
    </li>
</UL>
```

Here's my script:

```
$('.deleteAction').click(function(){
    var deleteActionID = $(this).attr("href");

    $.post(
        'cfc/test.cfc?method=deleteActionByID&returnformat=plain', 
        { id: deleteActionID }, 
        function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    );
    return false
});
```

Comment: If you have two elements, are you sure that you just aren't attaching it to them twice?

Comment: Not sure about the double posting, but maybe you can try changing this to a $('.deleteAction').on('click', function(){ ... }); call. Also, I don't know how widely approved this use of href would be. Maybe use data-id="10" and reference $(this).attr('data-id') and void(0) the href? I know it's all just attributes in the end and that retrun false handles it, but it is also just weird to see it like this. I've never seen anyone do it that way personally.

Comment: When using href, beware that IE will modify if by prepending the current location e.g. "http://www.somehost.so/deleteAction"

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: I tried "$('.deleteAction').on('click', function(){ ... });" and get this error "$(".deleteAttachment").on is not a function". Needless to day I'm fairly new to jQuery.

Comment: Please extend your JS a bit: 1) Wrap (if not yet done) the `click()` in a `$(document).ready()` event. 2) The anoynmous function for your `click()` event has a parameter `event`. Add it and within that function do a `event.preventDefault();`. That is what I can see after a quick review.

Answer (score 2):

I think your href is causing the listitem to be "clicked" again, engaging the jquery command the second time.  That is, you click the listitem and the jquery and the href are both activated and then the href "clicks" the listitem again, re-engaging your jquery script.  You might need to change this use of href in order to fix this.

Comment: thank you, I used rel instead of href to hold the id and it worked fine. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Weird... after FF update I'm getting the it’s making the same call twice again.

Comment: I think I found the problem, I'm using the portable Firefox and this seem to be my problem. I've tested the same scripts on a local install Firefox without any problem.